# Hourly timeline for the Exodus

Tags: history, passover, time

In order to get an idea of what it was like to have participated in the Exodus, I would like to see an hourly timeline for the process, starting after noon on the 14 Nissan 2448. The timeline should include as a minimum the time that matzos were baked to be eaten with the Korban Pesach, the time of the sacrifice and roasting of the Korban Pesach and the time that matzos were baked before Klal Israel left Egypt in the morning. I would also like to know what did  Klal Israel do after eating the  Korban Pesach and before leaving.

Answer (score 1):

So far, I have found from Rav Zvi Silber's sefer:
[image]

Comment: When you have the chance, consider using the new tables feature and writing this out, to make it accessible to the visually impaired and search engines.